# woocommerce single and archive functions works well on index page but they don't work from other pages

Tags: woocommerce

I need to use the woocommerce functions both individually and using hooks, if I use any of the following functions or hook in index.php file and preview a product page it loads the right content.

```
woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
woocommerce_template_single_rating();
woocommerce_template_single_price();
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

When I use the above functions or hook from a another php file add_to_cart.php etc. via require_once. and on index.php echo $content;
woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart() gives error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_type() on string in E:\xampp\htdocs\editorall\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php on line 1620

woocommerce_template_single_rating(); gives error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_rating_count() on string in E:\xampp\htdocs\editorall\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\rating.php on line 28

woocommerce_template_single_price(); gives error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on string in E:\xampp\htdocs\editorall\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\price.php on line 25

do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); gives error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_rating_count() on string in E:\xampp\htdocs\editorall\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\rating.php on line 28

But the following functions don't give error as the title and excerpt is not limited to woocommerce:

```
woocommerce_template_single_title();
woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();
```

Used simple:

```
woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
```

or return like this using buffering:

```
ob_start();
woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart
$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
```

Non works.

Comment: Maybe you have to load WP functions first: `$path = preg_replace('/wp-content(?!.*wp-content).*/','',__DIR__);   include($path . 'wp-load.php');`

Comment: I added your $path... code at the top of functions.php. I didn't notice any difference.